# Make ChatGPT answer in all rows in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, artificial-intelligence, google-sheets-api, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I got an google sheets with 200+ types of flowers under "name". I have made another column with called "what" where I want to output "What is" + the flowers name. I have integrated chatgpt and google sheets with the extension GptForWork.

Here's a screenshot of what i'm trying to do:[image]

I dont feel like going through all the 200+ columns and pasting that in. What can I do to make all the answers go under "what"?

Comment: why wouldn't you just put =GPT(D2)?

Comment: @MattKing That's actually what I did. Did not get it in the picure tho. Still have the problem that I have to do that "D3", "D4" and so on with all my 200+ rows. Any suggestions on how to do all the rows in 1 click?

Comment: i mean, you just double click the bottom right corner of the cell and it automatically does it to all the cells in the column.  Literally just copy/paste, the range ref will change itself, that's how spreadsheets work!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your formula by the actual cell address:

```
=GPT("What is", B2)
```

This will allow you to drag down the formula below to apply it to all other rows.

**Result:**
[image]